# TeX files got overwritten during input

Tags: input

I'm quite new to LaTeX.
I'm writing notes on a course at School. Found out that the document was going to be quite large so I tried to divide it into two documents, which was supposed to be imported (`\input`) into a main LaTeX file. During try out after looking through this page for relevant solutions both documents ended up like:

```
\relax

\@setckpt{/Users/Morten/Desktop/UiB/H2013/PTEK354/Kap1,1-1,3.tex}{
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\setcounter{enumi}{0}
\setcounter{enumii}{0}
\setcounter{enumiii}{0}
\setcounter{enumiv}{0}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\setcounter{mpfootnote}{0}
\setcounter{part}{0}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}
\setcounter{paragraph}{0}
\setcounter{subparagraph}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{currfiledepth}{0}
}
```

What happened?

The main file (`main.tex` (*please change to your used name!*)):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{standalone} 
\begin{document} 
\input{Kap1,1-1,3}  % add the exact filenames here please!
\input{Kap1,4}      % add the exact filenames here please!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try adding a little more info, a mwe or what packages you have...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sorry for the annoying problem. Did you use `\input` or `\include`? How were the files named?

Comment: Most likely, you used `\include` with a character in the filename that TeX could not handle so it over-wrote the `.aux` file contents on to the file (somehow).

Comment: During the try-out, it was problematic to input both the files i wanted. The main file:

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}

\input{Kap1,1-1,3}
\input{Kap1,4}

\end{document}

___

I think I tried both the \input and \include commands because none of them imported the documents the way i wanted it. Only the first document was imported, but no error showed up and the pdf file for the main document was produced (I continuously produce the pdf during writing to check for small errors).

Is it anyway possible to reverse the operation? from .pdf -> .tex

Comment: @egreg Update is above :)

Comment: Please, update your question, rather than using the space for comments. Be precise about the file names (also the name you gave to the main file can be relevant).

Comment: One solution may be to use filenames with only ASCII characters, no spaces or punctuation. (I don't know how well TeX deals with .,-; etc. in filename, but it definitely hates spaces.)

Comment: The first argument of `\@setckpt` is usually the file name argument of `\include`. Why is there a absolute path name, have you specified it in the argument of `\include`? And do *not* add the file extension `.tex`. Some systems (which TeX distribution are you using?) cannot handle extensions like `.tex.aux`, the second extension get lost and the `.tex` file is overwritten.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Can you add an answer? I believe the problem is exactly what you said.

Comment: @egreg Done. (But it wouldn't help the OP, because he has stopped visiting the site for nearly a year.)

Answer (score 4):

The code of the question (without the empty line)

```
\relax
\@setckpt{/Users/Morten/Desktop/UiB/H2013/PTEK354/Kap1,1-1,3.tex}{
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
...
```

is typical for `.aux` files for files that are included via `\include`.
Even if the file is not included, LaTeX will remember the counter settings
(page, equation, section, ...) via the `.aux` file.

However, the first argument of `\@setckpt` shows, that `\include` was used as:

```
\include{/Users/Morten/Desktop/UiB/H2013/PTEK354/Kap1,1-1,3.tex}
```

This is quite problematic:

- The absolute path name makes the document much less portable.
  If the document is moved or one of the directory is renamed,
  then the file name argument would be wrong.
- More severe is the extension. `\include` is quite dumb and adds `.aux` for its `.aux` file. But there are file systems, where file names with several dots are not allowed, Then the file name `Kap1,1-1,3.tex.aux` would be truncated to `Kap1,1-1,3.tex` and the original `.tex` file is overwritten.

  Therefore the extension `.tex` must be dropped for `\include`:

  ```
  \include{Kap1,1-1,3}
  ```